# How to create android widget selectable?

Tags: android, android-widget

The widget will look like standard application icon.
Once user clicks on the widget, it should be selected (highlighted with green background on HTC, with orange - on standard android).

How to achieve the same?

Upd. I've created it as selectable. Now I need to understand how to choose right background color/picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself - it can be easily done by defining `android:background="@drawable/shortcut_selector"`, then **shortcut_selector.xml** can contain something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_application_background" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focused_application_background" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the onReseive() deal with the listener.